# Why post method not working in angularjs in this example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Here I created sample for read and update json file. Reading the json file is working properly but I tried to update the json file that it show's Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
but if right click and check link that data is available. I don't know where I did mistake can any one help me this...

While Save
[image: While Save]
Data Available in that location
[image: Data Available]

```
file.json   
    [    
        {"name":"English","value":true},
        {"name":"Spanish","value":false},
        {"name":"German", "value":false},
        {"name":"Russian","value":false},
        {"name":"Korean", "value":false}
    ]
```

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.service('JSONService', function($http){         
    return{
        getJSON: function(){
            return $http.get('file.json')
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    };
 });

app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', 'JSONService','$http', function( $scope, JSONService, $http) {
  JSONService.getJSON().then(function(data){
       $scope.languages = data;
  });

//inputting json directly for this example
// $scope.languages = [        
//    {name:"English", value:true},
//    {name:"Spanish", value:false},
//    {name:"German", value:false},
//    {name:"Russian", value:false},
//    {name:"Korean", value:false}
//  ];

  $scope.save = function() {
 //   $http.post('file.json', $scope.languages).then(function(data) {
 //     $scope.msg = 'Data saved';
 //   });
    
$http({                
    url: 'file.json',
    method: "POST",
    data:$scope.languages,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Accept': 'application/json' 
    }
});

  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form>
    <div ng-repeat="lang in languages">
      <label>{{lang.name}}</label>
      <input type="checkbox" min="0" max="4" ng-model="lang.value" >
    </div>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you should use $http.post({});

Comment: can u put the syntax fully  @
Amit Ramoliya

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$http.post(site_url+'admin/addAdmin/',{
                        'vName'     : admin.vName,
                        'vEmail'     : admin.vEmail,
                        'vPassword'    : admin.vPass
                     }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                             //success
                     })
                     .error(function (evt) {
                            //error
                     });
```

Comment: And return response from backend in JSON. hope it works

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using server and directly calling the .json file then it should only be called as GET method. All the files are retrieved by default using HTTP GET method.

Since it is a pure JSON file and is not served through Server or any server side code, it won't be able to handle other HTTP methods such as POST, DELETE etc other than GET.

you want to save this post data to .json file? If this is your intention then this can not be done using $HTTP, you will need to handle this on server side

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `POST` to anything but a backend server. The browser is able to `GET` the file.json resource because is it able to simply read files from known locations. Browsers aren't able to directly write to files (typically, not including Chrome specific sandboxing using the [file](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage) [api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)) and need a server side element to process the `POST` request and then save the data.